# Nunit bug using keyboard keys

Tags: nunit

Can anyone reproduce this bug in Nunit? In the Nunit application, open an Nunit project with multiple tests. Right-click a test in the sidebar and select run in the context menu. This runs one test. Now, with the keyboard, browse to the top of the tree in the sidebar, push your *menu key* and select run. You expect all the child tests of the parent will run, but instead you find only the test you clicked on earlier is executed.

Comment: Confirmed! I was going to suggest that you report it as a bug to the NUnit project, but I can see that you have already [dealt with this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunitv2/+bug/1033537) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug reported to Nunit https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunitv2/+bug/1033537